# Too many re-renders issues in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, use-state

I want to use UseState to split the chat screen into Container and Presenter. But I've been going through too many rendering issues for two days now.

This is Container.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ChatsPresenter from "./ChatPresenter";

const ChatContainer = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState({
    user: [""],
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  try {
  } catch (e) {
    setError({ e: "에러가 났어요" });
  } finally {
    setLoading({ loading: false });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ChatsPresenter>{title.user}</ChatsPresenter>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChatContainer;
```

This is Presenter.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Loading from "../Loading";

const ChatsPresenter = ({ title, loading, error }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Container title="Kim" />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ChatsPresenter;
const Container = styled.div`
  font-size: 14px;
`;
```

This is index.jsx

```
import ChatContainer from "./ChatContainer";
export default ChatContainer;
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you update your state on every render, and this causes in a new re-render. You should wrap this in a [`\[useEffect\]` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), if you only want to fire it once.

```
useEffect(() => {

      try {
      } catch (e) {
        setError({ e: "에러가 났어요" });
      } finally {
        setLoading({ loading: false });
      }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue is the following code:

```
 try {
  } catch (e) {
    setError({ e: "에러가 났어요" });
  } finally {
    setLoading({ loading: false });
  }
```

Whenever your component renders, you change the state and it re-renders it. To aviod this you can use useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(error){
   //set your states
 }
})
```